# How to delete all newline characters from a list in Python

Tags: python, file, split

So I'm creating a program to read pdfs to text files, but every time I run my code, the newline characters pop up in the list for the text file. I have tried numerous methods including strip(), split() and replace(), but the characters just won't go away. If anyone could help me out, that'd be great. Snippet posted below:

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf

# creating an object 
file = open(PDF_FILENAME_DIRECTORY, "rb")

# creating a pdf reader object
fileReader = pdf.PdfFileReader(file)

# print the number of pages in pdf file
textData = []

for pages in fileReader.pages:
    theText = pages.extractText()

    # for char in theText:
    #   theText.replace(char, "\n")

    textData.append(theText)

final_list = []

for i in textData:
    final_list.append(i.strip('\n'))

# [s.strip('\n') for s in theText]
# [s.replace('\n', '') for s in theText]


# text_data = []

# for elem in textData:
#         text_data.extend(elem.strip().split('n'))  

# for line in textData:
#     textData.append(line.strip().split('\n'))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

import os.path

save_path = "FILENAME_SAVEPATH_DIRECTORY"

name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file + ".txt")   

file1 = open(completeName, "w")

file1.write(str(final_list))

file1.close()
```

[Sample output of code as a list in a text file. I want to take out the '\n' characters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5585u.png)

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Can you please share the content of the file after it is read into python?

Comment: `file1.write(str(final_list))` is almost certainly not what you want, unless you want to see a Python list display with brackets around the whole thing and quotes around each line.

Comment: Meanwhile, are you actually looking at the strings in `final_list` and seeing newlines there, or could it be that you just have one or more blank lines between each non-blank one?

Comment: Sample output posted in edit.

Comment: For future reference: don't post a screenshot of textual output or error messages. That's unhelpful to most people. Instead copy the actual output as text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on this line:

```
file1.write(str(final_list))
```

This invokes the `__str__` method of the `list` type, which uses `repr` to stringify the elements in the list, which is what is causing your output to look the way it does.

Do this instead:

```
for line in final_list:
    file1.write(line)
```

Comment: It finally works! Thank you so much! I was just starting to consider becoming an Anthropology major instead haha.

Comment: Quick question for reference, do you know if it is possible to write to a file and then read from it in the same code for example to strip characters after? I know that one could read a file and then write over it, but that would replace all of the text in that file with new text.